# psycopg2.NotSupportedError: INSERT with ON CONFLICT clause cannot be used with table that has INSERT or UPDATE rules

Tags: database, postgresql, rules, insert-update

When i'm creating a update RULE beside of CONFLICT clause then that error is throwing.

Here my conflict code

```
 insert_query = "INSERT INTO my_company (id, name, login, logout) VALUES %s\
                    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING"
```

my update RULE

```
CREATE RULE log_shoelace AS ON UPDATE TO my_company
    WHERE NEW.login <> OLD.login or NEW.logout <> OLD.logout
    DO INSERT INTO my_company VALUES (
    new.id, new.name, new.login, new.logout, new.interval_time, current_date);
```

my_company table field contains id, name, login. logout, interval_time, today.

if any data is updated then insert those data into same table.
But here i can't use CONFLICT and RULE in the same time. So in this case what can i do?

Thanks.

Table creation and sequence creation for testing:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS my_company_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.my_company
( id            integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_company_id_seq'::regclass)
, name          character varying(50)
, login         time without time zone
, logout        time without time zone
, interval_time time without time zone
, today         date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
, CONSTRAINT my_company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) 
);
```

Comment: Do you want to insert on conflict or update on conflict? It seems like you're trying to do an `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`. It looks like you don't need a rule at all to me. What are the data types for `login` and `logout`? If they're `timestamp`, it's unlikely they'd ever be equal.

Comment: login and logout both are TIME data type

Comment: my conflict is for insert and rule is for update

Comment: but without creating a RULE how can i insert data into today fields when something will be updated?

Comment: I guess I'm having a hard time determining when you want to update and when you want to insert a new row. It looks like you want to insert a new row when `login` or `logout` are new values. When would you be updating that row? If `id` is of type `SERIAL`, `BIGSERIAL` or following some user defined `SEQUENCE` when would the conflict occur where you want to `DO NOTHING`?

Comment: I have some data and these data will be updated for everyday.  "today' is a field of my table, in this field current_date will_be inserted when others field will be update according to the id (primary key). my id is integer type.

Comment: CREATE TABLE public.my_company
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('my_company_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying(50),
  login time without time zone,
  logout time without time zone,
  interval_time time without time zone,
  today date DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  CONSTRAINT my_company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

Comment: Take a look at this SQLFiddle and let me know if you still think you need a `RULE`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/073e9/16. Unless I'm missing something, you get the same results using `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT UPDATE`. Except there are times where your `RULE` will fail on a duplicate key violation.

Comment: sorry! I've used this before. It's not my result. Only current_date will be insert for a particular id's login or logout when will be updated. But in this case at first is being insert current_date for every each row today. Still i need a update RULE

Comment: in one word, without update login or logout,  current_date won't be insert into today field. So i need a RULE. Can i use any condition into conflict such like https://pastebin.com/He6U63L0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ON CONFLICT` directive should go in your rule body:

```
CREATE RULE log_shoelace AS 
    ON UPDATE TO my_company
        WHERE NEW.login <> OLD.login or NEW.logout <> OLD.logout
    DO 
        INSERT INTO my_company VALUES (
            new.id, new.name, new.login, new.logout, new.interval_time, current_date)
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING
```

Good to say, `ON CONFLICT` directives only work when the target table has some constraint to defer the conflict. Otherwise, you'll have runtime errors, like:

```
No unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification.
```